# SVN commit using cruise control

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, cruisecontrol.net

greetings all,

when trying to commit into tortoise svn using cruise control i am getting an exception

```
[SVN commit: warn] source control failure (GetModifications): Unable to execute file
[ c:\sand\doc\svn ]. The file may not exist or may not be executable.
```

where "c:\sand\doc" is my working directory. In this dir structure nowhere i have a dir named svn. The structure only contains "**.svn**" folder.

can any one help in resolving this exception...

regards.
**pratap**

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the folder containing svn.exe to your path on the CC server, or specify a full path to the exe where you attempt the commit.

Comment: What's the error when you use the full path? If it's the same, you've likely changed it in the wrong place...

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the **subversion** (command line client) executable in your path (svn.exe) not the **TortoiseSVN** (windows GUI) executable (TortoiseSVN.exe).

CruiseControl.net uses the command line tool to run the check for modifications.

You can get the binaries [here](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows)

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the Subversion .exe path in CruiseControl's sourcecontrol block:

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
  <executable>C:\Program Files\svn\bin\svn.exe</executable>
etc...
</sourcecontrol>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's trying to find the svn executable in the c:\sand\ folder, so I'm guessing that you've mixed up your configuration somewhere?